# Cons Data Type Outside Recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm trying to write a function which recursively goes through a data structure which internally uses a list once without modifying it. I'm having trouble prepending the element again outside of the recursion so that it won't dead loop.

```
difference (Set ((element, count) : set)) (MultiSet set')
    | ... = difference (Set ((element, count) : set)) (Set set') -- Prepends tuple inside the recursion
    | ...
```

What I need is a way of prepending the tuple (element, count) in front of the `set` without including it in the recursive call from `difference`.

What's an easy/standard way of doing this?

Comment: I don't understand your question: can you elaborate? Can't you define some helper function such as `prepend (Set set) x = Set (x:set)` to help with your task?

Comment: What does `difference` actually return?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid: It return the difference of two sets e.g. all elements from the right set are removed from the left one


chi: In the recursion I need to iterate over the list inside the `Set` but prepend the leading elements before the recursion so that they won't be extracted over and over again

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you *might* be looking for is

```
| ... = Set ((element, count) : difference set (Set set'))
```

No? How about this:

```
| ... = let Set set2 = difference set (Set set') in Set ((element, count) : set2)
```

(I'm assuming that `Set` is just `data Set x = Set [x]`.)

Comment: Doesn't work because `difference` returns a `Set a` and you can't prepend a tuple to that. Also difference takes a `Set a` and a `Set a` but you're giving it a tuple list and a `Set a`.

Comment: @user3764804 How about now?

Comment: Couldn't match expected type `Set a` with actual type `[(a, Integer)]` at `difference set (Set set')`

Comment: Without seeing more of your code (.e.g, the type signature for `difference`, the definition of `Set`, etc.) it's difficult to tell what's up.

Comment: You don't need to know more to get the syntax right but I solved it anyway using anti-patterns (indexes).

Here are the requested information though:
`data Set set = Set [(set, Integer)] deriving (Eq, Show)`
`difference :: Ord a => Set a -> Set a -> Set a`